# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined at jquery.dataTables.yadcf.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, yadcf

Yadcf 0.9.1 plugin is working fine for normal data using data table 1.10.13 but when I assigned it to ajax data receiving from web service, received error as-

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined at jquery.dataTables.yadcf.min.js:1

I have put all datatable/yadcf js and css into masterTemplate.xhtml,which already contains `jquery-1.11.2.min.js`
I have added jsFiddle without any result as I am fetching data from **web service.**

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f0exhc70/)

Thanks

[image: image when we load window for first time]

[image: image after loading window for 2nd time]

Comment: Where in your code are you indicating what data goes into what column? It looks like you have more columns defined in the "yadcf" plugin versus the actual number of columns based on your picture.

Comment: It's matter of js files sequence. Instead of chosen we can use select function. here s running code :http://live.datatables.net/dotoduju/1/edit

Comment: @PratikPowar you were using old version of yadcf, always use the latest.. see working jsbin test page http://live.datatables.net/dotoduju/4/edit

Comment: @Daniel,oops I'm still getting that **mData** error. when we load window for first time it shows filters to only  some columns not all but after loading window again, it shows filters for all columns.

Comment: @PratikPowar, I can't help without a test page

Comment: @Daniel, https://jsfiddle.net/f0exhc70/2/ This is want i have implemented.

Comment: @PratikPowar, I can't help without a live test page / production, if you will have one let me know...

Comment: @Daniel, it seems quite impossible for me to post test page having data called from web service,but I can explain scenario as i have two pages. On click of project column of first page we get second page & for both i have added yadcf js/css but in masterTemplate.xhtml,might be sequence of js is behind this error.

Comment: @Daniel,It was working once but not now and when i debugged,found that widget is not updating/appending columns of second page,so filter get assigned to only first 3 columns of second page

Answer (score 0):

Not sure as to that error message but you didn't see any data because you were using an old (relatively) version on yadcf in which was a bug in a 
yadcf / Chosen / server side scenario

anyway it was fixed recently, so use `0.9.2.beta.3` see working [jsbin test page](http://live.datatables.net/dotoduju/4/edit)